# DRF: custom ordering on related serializers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've got two serializers one for an Instructor and one for a Course. The Instructor serializer has a defined relationship to the courses like so:

`courses = CourseSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)`

**How do I specify an order to the courses in the instructor serializer?**

Note: I have defined the `ordering` value in the Course Meta class, but it is the default sorting I want everywhere else. What I want is a custom ordering for api output (specifically dept, number, -semester rather than the default -semester).

Comment: There was an [issue](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/1005) for this (I believe the same one), which has a potential solution.  Secondarily there is another way, however I think you'd need [another serializer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-rest-framework/L9aXnwS4AQw)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Since it is read only, wouldn't it be just as easy to use a serializer method for that field?

```
class InstructorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    courses = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_courses(self, obj):
         ordered_queryset = <do your magic here>
         return CourseSerializer(ordered_queryset, many=True, context=self.context).data
```

Answer (score 12):

Since Django 1.7, you can specify a queryset for `prefetch_related`. Using prefetch incurs just one additional database query instead of one per parent object with `SerializerMethodField`.

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from django.db.models import Prefetch

class InstructorViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Instructor.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch(
        'courses',
        queryset=Course.objects.order_by('dept', 'number')))
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should modulate the ordering via the viewset queryset. I would imagine the following:

```python
queryset = Instructor.objects.select_related('courses').order_by('courses__number')
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just reorder the Instructors? I want to reorder the Courses in the InstructorSerializer.

Answer (score -3):

This should be doable simply by providing an ordered `queryset` argument to your field declaration:

```python
class InstructorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    courses = CourseSerializer(
        queryset=Course.objects.order_by('...'),
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
    )
```

Further details: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#the-queryset-argument

Comment: `ModelSerializer`s don't accept a `queryset` parameter.