# Serializing a reverse foreign key field w/ a custom related manager in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

All,

I have 2 models linked together via a foreign key.  I am using a custom related manager on the reverse field.

**models.py:**

```
class Foo(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=23)
  bar = models.ForeignKey("Bar", related_name="foos")

class Bar(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=42)
  my_custom_manager = MyCustomManager()

class MyCustomManager(models.Manager):
  use_for_related_fields = True

  def get_queryset(self):
    if self.instance.is_special():
      return do_something_special() # returns a list of Foos
    return super(MyCustomManager, self).get_queryset()
```

To use this I use the following code:

```
my_bar_instance.foos.add(my_foo_instance)
my_bar_instance.foos(manager="my_custom_manager").all()
```

I know that this is a contrived example, but trust me that sometimes I need to do non-standard things when adding objects to this field.  Anyway, this code works fine.  The problem is when I try to serialize it.

**serializers.py:**

```
class FoosField(serializers.RelatedField):

    queryset = Foo.objects.all()

    list_serializer_class = ListSerializer

    def to_representation(self, value):        
        if not value:
            return {}

        from .some_other_package import FooSerializer
        serializezr = FooSerializer()
        representation = serializezr.to_representation(value)
        return representation

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        if not data:
            return None

        from .some_other_package import FooSerializer
        serializer = FooSerializer()
        internal_value = serializer.to_internal_value(data)
        return internal_value

class BarSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Bar
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'foos',
        )

    foos = BarField(many=True, required=False, allow_null=True, queryset=Foo.objects.all())
```

It is just outputing an empty list for the "foos" field.  I suspect this is because it is calling the reverse relationship field `foos` directly instead of specifying the custom manager `foos(manager="my_custom_manager")`.  Any idea on how to tell Django Rest Framework to use the custom manager?

Thanks

Comment: I didn't fully understand what you're doing here with the custom manager, but.... as far as the serializer goes - does this work for you? `foos = BarField(many=True, required=False, allow_null=True, queryset=Bar.my_custom_manager.all())`

Comment: You're going to need to somehow override how DRF gets the value from the object. There should be a method for it, I don't know it off the top of my head.

Comment: @zEro - That's an excellent suggestion.  Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: @KevinBrown - I've done something similar, but not as elegant as overriding a single method.

Answer (score 1):

Use [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) to define a function, where you can process your queryset however you want. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33402175/drf-custom-ordering-on-related-serializers/33512488#33512488) for example.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done.  But it's ugly:

**serializers.py:**

```
class FoosChildField(ManyRelatedField):

  def get_attribute(self, instance):
    manager = self.child_relation.manager
    if manager:
      relationship = getattr(instance, manager.get_name())
      return relationship.all() if (hasattr(relationship, 'all')) else relationship
    super(FoosChildField, self).get_attribute(instance)

class FoosField(serializers.RelatedField):

    queryset = Foo.objects.all()

    list_serializer_class = ListSerializer

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      manager = kwargs.pop("manager", None)
      super(FoosField, self).__init__(**kwargs)
      self.manager = manager

    @classmethod
    def many_init(cls, *args, **kwargs):        
      list_kwargs = {'child_relation': cls(*args, **kwargs)}
      for key in kwargs.keys():
        if key in MANY_RELATION_KWARGS:
            list_kwargs[key] = kwargs[key]
      return FoosChildField(**list_kwargs)

    def to_representation(self, value):        
        if not value:
            return {}

        from .some_other_package import FooSerializer
        serializezr = FooSerializer()
        representation = serializezr.to_representation(value)
        return representation

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        if not data:
            return None

        from .some_other_package import FooSerializer
        serializer = FooSerializer()
        internal_value = serializer.to_internal_value(data)
        return internal_value

class BarSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Bar
        fields = (
            'id',
            'name',
            'foos',
        )

    foos = BarField(many=True, required=False, allow_null=True, queryset=Foo.objects.all(), manager=Bar.my_custom_manager)
```

I've added one new class (`FoosChildField`) and two new methods (`__init__` & `many_init`).

Basically, I pass the manager to the DRF related field instance, which in turn passes it to the DRF "child" field (since this is a list serializer).  The `get_attribute` fn uses that manager to get the actual values.

Yuck.